# Understanding angular js filter syntax according to documentation

Tags: angularjs

According to [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) the "currency" filter takes `amount` as the first parameter given the following syntax:

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : amount : symbol}}
```

But in the following example it never passed the `amount` as a parameter:

```
<span id="currency-default">{{amount | currency}}</span>
```

I'm assuming that `amount` in the example refers to the `currency_expression` in the syntax as written in the documentation. They could have written it in the documentation in this way:

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol}}
```

Another example is the `filter` [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) with the following syntax:

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : array : expression : comparator}}
```

But in the following example it never specified the "source array" parameter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
```

I'm assuming that `friendObj in friends` in the example refers to the `filter_expression` and `search` refers to the `array` if we're going to follow the syntax as written in the documentation. They could have written it in the documentation in this way:

```
{{ filter_expression_that_returns_array | filter : expression : comparator}}
```

I'm not so sure if I'm missing something but the documentation doesn't make sense to me given their examples.

My question is, should I simply ignore what the documentation says that the first parameter must be the input?

Comment: From experience, it is as you described it (the HTML syntax in the docs has one extra parameter - the expression that appears before the pipe should **not** appear after the filter as well). I would very much like to know, though, why it appears this way in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth (since by experience we already know it is like that), the source code indicates that the expression only needs to be before the `|`.

Using the source for **[version 1.2.16](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js)** and without going into much detail:

**[ng/parse.js#L103](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L103)**

```
// In the OPERATORS hash:
var OPERATORS = {
    ...
    '|': function (self, locals, a, b) {
        return b(self, locals)(self, locals, a(self, locals));
    },
    ...
```

**[ng/parse.js#L579](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L579)**

```
// `Parser`'s `filter()` method:
Parser.prototype = {
    ...
    filter: function() {
      var token = this.expect();
      var fn = this.$filter(token.text);
      var argsFn = [];
      while (true) {
        if ((token = this.expect(':'))) {
          argsFn.push(this.expression());
        } else {
          var fnInvoke = function(self, locals, input) {
            var args = [input];
            for (var i = 0; i < argsFn.length; i++) {
              args.push(argsFn[i](self, locals));
            }
            return fn.apply(self, args);
          };
          return function() {
            return fnInvoke;
          };
        }
      }
    },
    ...
```

---

So, what did we learn ?

```
if ((token = this.expect(':'))) {
  argsFn.push(this.expression());
```

The parser will get all tokens after the filter (separated by `:`) and put them in an array (`argsFn`).

---

```
var args = [input];
for (var i = 0; i < argsFn.length; i++) {
  args.push(argsFn[i](self, locals));
}
```

At "runtime" (when the actual filtering is hapenning) an new array will be created (`args`) which will contain `input` (*but what is input ? more on that later*) and each parameter token that was previosuly stored in `argsFn`.

---

```
return fn.apply(self, args);
```

This `args` array will be the arguments list to the filtering function.

So, `args` contains `input` and the tokens after `filter_name` (as in `expression | filter_name : param1 : param2`).
If we can convince ourselves that `input` is indeed the expression (appearing on the left of the `|`, then we should be convinced that there is no need to have the expression appear as the first parameter **after** `filter_name`.

---

```
var fnInvoke = function(self, locals, input) {
...
return function() {
  return fnInvoke;
};
```

`filter()` returns an anonymous function that when executed returns the function `fnInvoke`.
`input` is the third argument assed to `fnInvoke` when it is executed.

---

Now lets get back to the `|` operator:

```
'|': function (self, locals, a, b) {
    ...
```

It will result in calling this anonymous function with `a` and `b` being the left-hand side (`expression`) and the right-hand side (`filter_name:param1:param2`) respectively.

<sub>(In fact `a` and `b` are not the left- and right-hand sides, but they are functions that when executed return the result of evaluating the left- and right-hand sides in a given context (i.e. scope).</sub>

---

```
return b(self, locals)(self, locals, a(self, locals));
```

This tells us that the function returned by calling the anonymous function returned by `filter()` (`b(self, locals)`) will be executed with the following arguments:

```
`self`, `locals`, `a(self, locals)`
```

Which means that the mysterious `input` parameter (remember it was the 3rd argument of `fnInvoke` ?) is `a(self, locals)`.
And `a(self, locals)` is basically the result of evaluating the left-hand side argument of the `|` operator in the context of the current scope, e.g. the result of evaluating a string (`'someExpression'`) to the value of the property in the current scope (`$scope.someExpression`).

---

I don't know if you are convinced (I don't think I would have been).
I left much detail out of the explanation, but the interested reader can delve into that source and convince themselves :)

<sub>I feel kind of bad for posting such a longish answer with so little practical value. Sigh...</sub>

Comment: It may not have practical value but it helps remove the confusion. It's coming from official documentation, how could we expect any less? The flaws in the docs were consistent (if they are indeed flaws). I just can't take the examples by faith without understanding what's actually happening.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would always read the source code when in doubt.

For your `<span id="currency-default">{{amount | currency}}</span>` example:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L50

```
currencyFilter.$inject = ['$locale'];
function currencyFilter($locale) {
  var formats = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
  return function(amount, currencySymbol){
    if (isUndefined(currencySymbol)) currencySymbol = formats.CURRENCY_SYM;
    return formatNumber(amount, formats.PATTERNS[1], formats.GROUP_SEP, formats.DECIMAL_SEP, 2).
                replace(/\u00A4/g, currencySymbol);
  };
}
```

Looks to me like `amount` then `currency`, so input must be first parameter.

**Update**.

Source for `filter` in HTML Template Binding context.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L116

```
function filterFilter() {
  return function(array, expression, comparator) {
    if (!isArray(array)) return array;
```

First `if` is a check for `array`, aka input, as first parameter.

Comment: What yoh say applies to using the filter in JavaScript. With HTML `|` syntax it is different. If you want to look at the source, you have to look at how expressions in `{{ }}` are parsed/evaluated.

Comment: But +1 for looking at the source :)